# Paginacion, valores, numeracion, php, javascript

Tags: javascript, paginación

este codigo lo encontre por internet. Estoy mostrando solo la parte de paginación. Mi problema y pregunta es como hacer que cuando la pagina sea 1 no aparezca ni `-1` ni `0`; o cuando llege a la ultima pagina no se agregen 2 más adelante.

```
$start_loop = $page -2;
$end_loop = $page + 2;

if($_GET['page']>$totalpages || $_GET['page']<=0){
    header('Location:index.php?page=1');
}

if($page > 1)
{
 echo "<a class='pagina' href='index.php?page=1'>Primera</a>";
 echo "<a class='pagina' href='index.php?page=".($page - 1)."'><<</a>";
}

for($i=$start_loop; $i<=$end_loop; $i++)
{     
 echo "<a class='pagina' href='index.php?page=".$i."'>".$i."</a>";
}

if($page < $totalpages)
{
 echo "<a class='pagina' href='index.php?page=".($page + 1)."'>>></a>";
 echo "<a class='pagina' href='index.php?page=".$totalpages."'>Última</a>";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás asignando inicio y fin del ciclo, sin tomar en cuenta la página actual, por eso se muestran enlaces que no corresponden.

```
$start_loop = $page -2;
$end_loop = $page + 2;
```

Para evitarlo, debes analizar que inicio y fin estén entre 1 y el total de páginas disponibles:

```
// Asigna el inicio del ciclo y verifica que no es menor que 1
$start_loop = $page - 2;
if($start_loop < 1) {
    $start_loop = 1;
}
// Asigna el final del ciclo agregando la cantidad de enlaces a mostrar - 1
$end_loop = $start_loop + 4; // Mostrar máximo 5 enlaces
// Ahora verifica que el final del ciclo no es mayor que la última página
if($end_loop > $totalpages) {
    $end_loop = $totalpages;
}
```

Ahora, el problema es que si estás en la última página, el inicio y fin de ciclo van a ser iguales y solo se va a mostrar un enlace, hay que garantizar que se muestren 5, si es que están disponibles. Agrega lo siguiente:

```
// La página actual está en el límite para mostrar solo los últimos enlaces
if($page >= ($totalpages - 2)) {
    // Garantizar que se muestran las últimas páginas
    $end_loop = $totalpages;
    // Recalcular el inicio
    $start_loop = $end_loop - 4;
    // Asegurar que no es menor que uno
    if($start_loop < 1) {
        $start_loop = 1;
    }
}
```

Hice este código sin probarlo, así que puede tener errores, además, podría simplificarse y mejorarse. Trata de entenderlo antes de usarlo en tu proyecto, no es buena idea copiar y pegar sin revisar.

Answer (score 0):

Gracias por la ayuda Triby. De hecho solo tuve que implementar el primer código que describes; al menos para lo que hacia fue suficiente.

```
// Asigna el inicio del ciclo y verifica que no es menor que 1
$start_loop = $page - 2;
if($start_loop < 1) {
    $start_loop = 1;
}
// Asigna el final del ciclo agregando la cantidad de enlaces a mostrar - 1
$end_loop = $start_loop + 4; // Mostrar máximo 5 enlaces
// Ahora verifica que el final del ciclo no es mayor que la última página
if($end_loop > $totalpages) {
    $end_loop = $totalpages;
}
```