# Como puedo hacer que los botones del paginado tengan un limite

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

acabo de realizar un paginado y funciona bien, sin embargo, los links a las diferentes paginas no tiene  limite, por lo que llega un punto en que no es obtimo.
Ejemplo:

Pocas paginas:

[image: Pocas paginas]

Muchas paginas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría que a cierto limite ya no mostrara mas algo así:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De esa forma al dar al botón < o > aparezca el resto de links

Este es mi código:

```
<div class="contenedor-anuncios">
    <?php
    include 'conexion.php';
    //Cantidad de registros por paginas
    $por_pagina = 9;

    if (isset($_GET['pagina'])) {
        $pagina = $_GET['pagina'];
    } else {
        $pagina = 1;
    }


    // La inicia en 0 y se multiplica $por_pagina

    $empieza = ($pagina - 1) * $por_pagina;
    // Seleccionar los registros  de la tabla con limit
    $re = mysqli_query($con, "select * from notas order by id desc limit $empieza, $por_pagina") or die(mysqli_error($con));
    while ($f = mysqli_fetch_assoc($re)) {
    ?>

        /**El conido va que se muestra va aquí, no lo pongo para no saturar de código**/


    <?php
    }
    ?>

</div>
<div>
    <center>
        <?php
        //Seleccionar todo de la tabla usuarios
        $res = mysqli_query($con, "select * from notas");

        //Contar el total de registros
        $total_registros = mysqli_num_rows($res);
        //Usando ceil para dividir el total de registros entre $por_pagina
        $total_paginas = ceil($total_registros / $por_pagina);

        //Primera pagina
        echo "<a class='boton boton-amarillo' href='anuncios.php?pagina=1'> Primera </a>";
        //Links numerales
        for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_paginas; $i++) {
            echo "<a class='boton boton-amarillo' href='anuncios.php?pagina=" . $i . "'>" . $i . "</a>";
        }
        //Ultima Pagina
        echo "<a class='boton boton-amarillo' href='anuncios.php?pagina=" . $total_paginas . "'> Ultima </a>";
        ?>
    </center>
</div>
```

¿Alguna idea de como hacer esto o algo similar?

Gracias de antemano!

Comment: [Esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/418643/paginacion-valores-numeracion-php-javascript/418668#418668) podría servirte.

Comment: Gracias, en parte si soluciona lo que quiero hacer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución que encontré para esto es la siguiente, pero importante resaltar que esto en especifico solo funciona en rangos de 10 en 10 (Ósea nuestra mínimo 1 objeto y máximo 10)

```
   <?php
   $pagina = 10; //Sustituye a la pagina actual que es obtenida con: $_GET['pagina']
   $totalpaginas = 12; // Sustituye al total de paginas que es obtenido por:
                       //Seleccionar todo de la tabla elementos
                       //$res = mysqli_query($con, "select * from notas");
                       //Contar el total de registros
                       //$total_registros = mysqli_num_rows($res);
                       //ceil para dividir el total de registros entre $por_pagina
                       //$total_paginas = ceil($total_registros / $por_pagina);
//Arreglo de los links
    $rangoinicio = 0;
    $rangofin = 0;
    $y = 1;
    $z = 10;
    if ($pagina >= $y && $pagina <= $z) {
        $rangoinicio = $y;
        $rangofin = $z;
        for ($i = $rangoinicio; $i <= $rangofin; $i++) {
            print(" " . $i . " ");
        }
    } else {
        $a = 10;
        $bandera = True;
        while ($bandera == True) {
            if ($pagina >= ($y + $a) && $pagina <= ($z + $a)) {
                $rangoinicio = ($y + $a);
                $rangofin = ($z + $a);
                if ($rangofin > $totalpaginas) {
                    $rangofin = $totalpaginas;
                }
                //$rangofin = $totalpaginas;
                for ($i = $rangoinicio; $i <= $rangofin; $i++) {
                    print(" " . $i . " ");
                }
                break;
            } else {
                $a = $a + 10;
            }
        }
    }
    //Fin del areglo
    ?>
```

Espero haberme explicado!