# Paginación responsive suprimiendo algunos números de pagina

Tags: php, html, bootstrap

He escrito el código para hacer una paginación, el cúal funciona correctamente, pero cuando se crean más de 15 páginas el diseño *responsive* se sale del `div` del contenedor y da un mal aspecto.

Pienso poner un límite dinámico que diga cuando el número total de paginas a crear sea superior a *100* entonces se formatee de la siguiente manera:

```
<First Prev 1 2 3 4 ... 9 10 Next Last>
```

Mi código va así :

```html
<section class="pagination">
    <div class="container mt-5">
        <nav data-pagination>
            <ul class="pagination ">
                <li class="page-item <?php echo $_GET['page_reviews']<=1? 'disabled' : ''?>"><a class="page-link" href="index.php?page_reviews=<?php echo ''.$_GET['page_reviews']-1 ?>">Anterior</a></li>
                <?php  for($i=0;$i<$pages;$i++): ?>
                    <li class="page-item <?php echo $_GET['page_reviews']==$i+1 ? 'active' : ''  ?>">
                        <a class="page-link" href="index.php?page_reviews=<?php echo $i+1?>">
                            <?php echo $i+1?>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <?php endfor?>
                        <?php ?>
                            <li class="page-item <?php echo $_GET['page_reviews']>= $pages? 'disabled' : ''?>"><a class="page-link" href="index.php?page_reviews=<?php echo ''.$_GET['page_reviews']+1 ?>">Siguiente</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</section>
```

Con este código se crean las páginas necesarias según hayan registros en la base de datos. Por ejemplo si hay 200 registros muestra 10 por página y crea 20 páginas. El problema lo encuentro en el diseño adaptable ya que crea la fila de 20 números de esta manera:

```
Anterior 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 Siguiente
```

Está cantidad de `ul` se sale del contenedor y se ve mal.

También me gustaría que el valor de los enlaces ocultos entre los `...` se pueda hacer dinámico para que se mantenga el diseño *responsive*.

Actualización:

Lo que he intentado es crear un subset o rangos para mostrar en la paginación que ya he creado pero no me funciona me salen los números de la paginacion desde el 1 hasta el último numero que haya y liego me salen varias veces ... 2 ... 1 ... etc.

```php
if($total_records > $per_page){
        echo "<center><a href='index.php?page=1'>First Page</a> ";

        // current page
        $current_page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] : 1;

        // Superset range of pages
        $superset_range = range(1, $total_pages);

        // subset range of pages to display
        $subset_range = range($current_page - 3, $current_page + 3);

        // adjust the range(if required)
        foreach($subset_range as $p){
            if($p < 1){
                array_shift($subset_range);
                if(in_array($subset_range[count($subset_range) - 1] + 1, $superset_range)){
                    $subset_range[] = $subset_range[count($subset_range) - 1] + 1;
                }
            }elseif($p > $total_pages){
                array_pop($subset_range);
                if(in_array($subset_range[0] - 1, $superset_range)){
                    array_unshift($subset_range, $subset_range[0] - 1);
                }
            }
        }

        // display intermediate pagination links
        if($subset_range[0] > $superset_range[0]){
            echo " ...&nbsp;";
        }
     
        foreach($subset_range as $p){
            echo "<li class="page-item"><a class="page-link"  href='index.php?page=$p'>$p</a>";

        }
           

        }
        if($subset_range[count($subset_range) - 1] < $superset_range[count($superset_range) - 1]){
            echo "&nbsp;... ";
        }

        echo " <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link"  href='index.php?page_reviews=$total_pages'>Last Page</a></li> ";  
      
}
```

Comment: Nos has expuesto bien lo que quieres, eso no hay duda, pero no lo que has hecho tu para conseguirlo, ni los errores que te ha dado al intentarlo, por lo tanto nos da la sensación que nos estas mandando una tarea en lugar de preguntarnos por un error concreto de programación. Puedes [edit] tu pregunta agregando lo que has intentado y donde te has encallado para que sea mejor recibida. Léete lo del [example] y [ask] para aprender a formular mejores preguntas, gracias.

Comment: Es posible que [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/418643/54039) te sirva de guía para mostrar solo algunos enlaces de paginación.